# How many combinations does this cube have and what is the probability that we get all of the same colour?

Tags: combinatorics

I recently came across a contraption. For those who can’t access the attached picture, here's the description:

> There is a contraption in the shape of a large transparent cube. Inside, the base of cube has $9$ cubical pockets with a (small) cube in each of them. Each small cube has $6$ different colors. Upon shaking this contraption, the small cubes shuffle between pockets.

I am wondering what is the probability that after shaking, all the cubes have the same color. Also what is the probability that they all have a different color? Any help would be appreciated.

So far I have figured out that each cube can fall into $9$ spaces with $6$ different colors so I think there are $6 \times 9 = 54$ combinations for one cube and then $54 \times 9 = 486$ for all cubes. I am just not sure if I am doing it correctly.
[image: Contraption]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints.

- Convince yourself that where the cubes end up does not have any
  influence on the answer to your question.
- Think about why your question is the same as "roll a die $9$ times.
  What is the probability that the $9$ results agree?"
- Solve that problem.

The cubes can't all have different colors since there are nine cubes and just six colors.

Comment: The second hint is very helpful as these are 9 smaller dice. So from what I understand rolling a die 9 times to get numbers from 1-9 (in any order). Is (1/6) to the 9th power. Am I correct in this calculation?

Comment: The probability of getting any particular sequence in a particular order (say 112111111) is $(1/6)^9$. That's not the same as the probability of a sequence with 8 ones and one 2.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand how that sequence is the same as getting for example 8 ones and then a 2 is the same 1/6 chance. Upon further thought, I also realized that when the dice are rolled the first time, the probability is 6/6 because the colour doesn't quite matter. After that, it is 6/6 times 1/6 to the power of eight. Is this a more accurate calculation?

Comment: Yes (and no). The probability for 9 ones is $(1/6)^9$. Same for  twos, or ... or 9 sixes. So the probability that the dice all agree is $6 \times (1/6)^9$. You reached the same conclusion by a different and equally valid argument.

Comment: How come it is to the 9th power? The first roll is 6/6 and after that, there are 8 dice left right? In that case wouldn't it be 1/6 to the eight power?

Comment: Once you see a 6 (or anything else) on the first roll the probability of matching it on the next 8 rolls is $(1/6)^8$, as you say. There are six possibilities for the first roll, so the probability that all the rolls match is $6 \times (1/6)^9 = (1/6)^8$. I think we really agree on the calculation.